# Force feedback electromagnetic power requirments

Tags: power, feedback, energy, electromagnetic

I want to design a force feedback system for a gun controller which will use an electromagnetic drive system to replicate gun recoil. I've explored a range of designs but they all seem to require a lot of power.

So my question is this: Does anyone know of any low power (15v max) linear actuator solutions which could be used which provide a rapid force feedback?

Comment: The impulse of recoil represents a high peak power in a short time interval. You'll probably want to use some sort of energy storage system (e.g., capacitor, spring) to spread the energy over a longer time in order to reduce the average power.

Comment: You can estimate the force of a guns recoil, for example read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoil and maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_of_firearms. Then you will have the *minimum* power needed. Once you have estimated that power, maybe come back and ask a question. Even if it seems like a lot of power, if you want lower power than that, you are going to have to compromise somewhere.

Comment: If you want to accurately replicate firearm recoil, you need a system that can provide *at least* the same amount of *energy* as is provided by the round in the firearm. Your *power* (instantaneous) requirement is also high due to the short duration of chemical combustion.

Comment: Does your system need to have the same recoil as an actual firearm? Usually a small force is enough to make a simulation feel real. If this is for a simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Really an interesting problem.  You could build a solenoid with a spring; try a flat face solenoid and "cock" the spring, either mechanically or with a ballscrew, and remove power to release it and drive a mass against a hard stop.  The energy from your round is 1/2 mV**2, and since you can't get the mass moving at the speed of the bullet, you will need to use a bigger mass and calculate the spring force so that the mass is at the appropriate speed when it hits the stop.  If your spring is affixed attached to the mechanism containing the stop, you will also feel  a lighter force in the opposite direction if as the spring accelerates the mass, so if you don't want this artifact, the spring must be fixed to an external point which is not part of the recoil assembly.

Answer (score 0):

So i don't know if you are trying to invent something new or just solve a problem that you might have encountered. But there is some work on a similar problem that is being done using linear motors. There is currently a US patent on a solution to simulating semi automatic gun recoil http://www.google.com/patents/US20130316308 .